# Obtaining the results of the threads in the sequence they were started

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I am accessing data from an api with the below mentioned endpoints:-

```
1.getProductList
2.getImageurlofProduct/productid
```

I am supposed to create an arraylist of hashmaps which contain productid,productprice and productimageurl of each product.From the main thread I spawn a thread-A to the first endpoint and as I parse through the result I spawn threads from thread A.

However the sequence in which those threads respond back to  threadA is not the same in which they were started. So i end up having the imageurl of product 2 added up to product with id 1.

How do i handle this. An algorithm should do fine for me. 
Please let me know if you want me to clarify something more

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use an `Executor` to spawn your threads, you can save all the returned `Future`s and then call `Future.get()` on them in the same order as they were started.

Read more here: [`ExecutorService`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#submit%28java.lang.Runnable%29) and [`Future`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html).

Comment: +1. Put the `Future`s in a `List` as you spawn the `Task` threads. When all the `Future`s reply true to `isDone()`, you have the results in order.